# Mounting a cifs share into a linux container with Docker Desktop

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I got Windows 10 (1909) running Docker Desktop (3.2.2) with wsl2 as engine.

I want to mount my network resources into my Linux container. They are located at `\\<ip>\<share>`. Windows user can access them. They should be accessible in container, preferably without sharing login credentials to the container.

I tried with bind and volume, without success. I tried with share path and mounted to a drive letter.

How can this be done?